# Linux Mint 17.3 screen is not automatically locked when I manually lock the screen

Tags: linux, linux-mint, screensaver

My problem is basically as the topic says.

I am using `GLMatrix` screensaver from xscreensaver. I set the delay before locking screen to immediately, lock the computer when inactive to after 1 minute.

The problem occurs after I lock the screen by myself either from menu or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.
I closed all application and waited for more than 1 minute. The screen is still not locked. However, when I reboot the system, the lock screen is doing its job normally.